# Prolog routes in directed graph

Tags: prolog

I am quite new to Prolog and want to create a program, where I can ask for a route with the predicate "`route(Startpoint,Endpoint,Route)`".

My code so far is:

```
% facts

connection(s1,s2).
connection(s2,s3).
connection(s3,s4).
connection(s4,s5).
connection(s5,s6).
connection(s6,s7).
connection(s7,s1).

% predicates

route1(X,Y,[X,Y]) :- connection(X,Y).
route1(X,Y,R) :- connection(X,Z), route1(Z,Y,RZ), R=[X|RZ].

route2(X,Y,[X,Y]) :- connection(Y,X).
route2(X,Y,R) :- connection(Z,X), route2(Z,Y,RZ), R=[X|RZ].

route(X,Y,R) :- route1(X,Y,R); route2(X,Y,R).
```

My code works for some routes, but not when it comes to a cycle (like in the facts above). How can I prevent in Prolog, that a station gets visited in a route multiple times?

For example when I ask "`?- route1(s1,s4,R).`", Prolog gives me the correct route "`[s1,s2,s3,s4]`" first, but it also gives me other routes like "`[s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s1, s2, s3, s4]`", "`[s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s1, s2, s3, s4]`" and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write:

```
route1(X,Y,[X,Y]) :- connection(X,Y).
route1(X,Y,R) :- connection(X,Z), route1(Z,Y,RZ),R=[X|RZ],       
                 sort(R,R1),length(R,N),length(R1,N1),
                 (N>N1->!,fail ;true).
```

`sort/2` removes duplicates so if you want your solution not to have duplicates the sorted list and the output list must have same length.

```
?- route1(s1,s4,R).
R = [s1, s2, s3, s4] ;
false.
```

Another ways to do that would be :

```
route1(X,Y,R):-route1(X,Y,[],R).

route1(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- connection(X,Y).
route1(X,Y,L,R) :- connection(X,Z),\+member(Z,L),
                   route1(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ),R=[X|RZ].
```

Example:

```
?- route1(s1,s4,R).
R = [s1, s2, s3, s4] ;
false.
```

Comment: It comes to an infinite loop when I ask for other routes than [s1,s2,s3,s4]. :/

Comment: Thanks!! Can you maybe explain me a bit more detailed what prolog does when it comes to the sort predicate?

Comment: Predefined sort/2 sort the list and also removes duplicates!! So if your list has duplicates N1 (length of sorted) will be N1>N and will be leaded to fail and stop else it will continue.

Comment: Ok, would it also be possible to make a list where it puts all the stations in and say somehow with the member predicate, that a station can't be visited multiple times?

Comment: Maybe you could keep a list of all stations visited and when you find duplicate stop....but you should check that  the duplicate is after the last station ....

Comment: Can you maybe help me doing this? I already looked up for hours and didn't find any solution. :/